# Set cause for custom exception

Tags: java

I'd been trying to set `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as cause of `NoSuchUserException`(for MyUser.class),but it doesn't work. The `Throwable` parameter represents the cause of the exception. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

```
   public class NoSuchUserException extends Exception {
        private int id = 0;
        private Throwable cause;
          public NoSuchUserException(int id, Throwable x) {
            super("User " + id + " does not exist");
            this.cause = x;
        }
    }

    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class MyUser {
        private String[] users;

        public MyUser(String[] users) {
            this.users = Arrays.copyOf(users, users.length);
        }

        public String getUser(int id) throws NoSuchUserException {
            try {
                someMethodThatThrows();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                throw new NoSuchUserException(id, e);
            }

            return users[id];
        }

        private void someMethodThatThrows() {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the cause to the parent constructor:

```
public class NoSuchUserException extends Exception {
    public int id = 0;
    public NoSuchUserException(int id, Throwable x) {
        super("User " + id + " does not exist", x);
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29).